# mysterious (empty) character

Tags: java

```
    String[] parts = msg.split(" +\n?");

    String room = parts[0];
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println("Laczenie do" + room + ", " + parts.length);
    for (String s : parts)
        System.out.println("-" + s + "-");
```

output:

```
  main                                                               

Laczenie do, 2
 --
 -main-
```

What is this first char? How to cut it using regexp?

Comment: what is the value of `msg`? `main`?

Comment: Please post ALL the referenced code.. (i.e, msg , main  etc)

Comment: msg = (few space) main (a lot of spacce) (new line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the empty string at the start of the string. Your regex splits on one or more spaces, optionally followed by a newline character. Since your string starts with spaces, the first split occurs around those spaces - the left-hand part is empty, the right-hand part is `main` etc.

Visualizing the spaces using `_`, your string looks like:

```
__main
```

So when you split it, it gets divided into the part before `__` (`""`) and the part after `__` (`"main"`).

What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I excepted that parts[0] will equals main

Comment: If your string had been `"start  main"`, would you still have expected `parts[0]` to equal main? If so, why?

Comment: string looks like `__main_____`, so why don,t exist last empty part, after `main`?

Comment: Interesting. I don't have Java installed. In Python, I get `['', 'main', '']` when I split that string, as expected.